# How to read data from a tool using python

Tags: python, user-interface, screen-scraping

I have a tool where there is an input field for entering a part number. After entering the part number it will give information like weight, height and other kind of details. We have a some 100 part numbers stored in one excel sheet. Using python I want to fetch each part number from excel sheet and input it in the tool and fetch the details of part number and store them in another excel sheet. Can anyone provide insight on how to read the details of each part number from tool using python. The tool does not have a database as it is stored in a server and we don't have APIs to access the database. Are there any libraries available in python to fetch data from tool without having to access the database.

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So you need something to read from the software's GUI without using an API or database. I suggest using code injection tools or libraries to automate GUI control such as [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) or [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Exactly!. I need to read from the tools GUI and there's no database or any other file to read from. So in this case, what u suggested ( pywinauto and pyautogui) will work ?